# Creating private deb packages for distribution

Tags: ros, rosmake, packages, rosdeb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to take my existing ROS packages and release different versions that can be installed and updated on a platform without a checkout of the source code repository (so no rosmake).

The current solution is copying over the compiled binaries manually and setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include all of the lib directories.

Is there a script or tool that will generate a binary-only deb package that I can distribute?  [Rosdeb](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdeb) looks close, but there isn't a lot of documentation on how to run it by hand.  Or alternatively, what's the best solution to move over the binaries without having to manually set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

---

Edit:  Unfortunately, this is all proprietary work, so I can't just piggyback onto the Willow servers.  ;)

My ideal quick solution would be something like:

`roscd my_secret_package`

`rosmake --make-binary-deb my_secret_package.deb -tag 0.1-2-3`

`scp my_secret_package.deb foo@bar:/some/path`

And later, if possible, I would find a way to make a quick apt-get repo, but I'm primarily interested in being able to make quick binary releases by hand.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11315/creating-private-deb-packages-for-distribution/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2011-09-26

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To get a proper answer to this, you probably want to join the Fuerte Infrastructure SIG: http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Planning/Infrastructure .  The code is there, but the SIG will deal with the issues of external users using it.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I addition to Ken's suggestion, you may want to release your stacks via the standard ROS [release process](http://www.ros.org/wiki/release). That creates `.deb` files on the Willow Garage servers. They can be installed as binaries on any Ubuntu system you need.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1